# bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph ERROR

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, bazel

i have some problem when i want to transfer my model using bazel to convert it.
i try this cmd:

```
$  bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph
```

here are the error:

> ERROR: Skipping 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph': no such package 'tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms': BUILD file not found on package path

can any body tell me how to use it?
thanks a lot

then i try this cmd:

```
$ bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:vgg_16_10000.pb
```

i put have graph_transforms in tools directory and `vgg_16_10000.pb` in `graph_transforms`.
and i still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run that first command (`bazel build`) you must have a BUILD file at the specified directory, which in this case is ***tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms***. Based on only the info you've provided, chances are you haven't actually cloned or downloaded the Tensorflow repository. You cannot simply run that command if you only have installed Tensorflow using **pip** or **conda install**, since those do not include the source code.

That should be enough information for you to decide whether you actually want to build sources or use the python API, as shown [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/summary/graph).

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the root of the tensorflow source directory   run `./configure` first:

```
$ ./configure
$ bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:summarize_graph
```